# How to interpret TfidfVectorizer output

Tags: tfidfvectorizer, nlp

I am doing sentiment analysis and for feature generation from text, I am using TF-IDF method but I am not able interpret the output.

I have used the TfidfVectorizer function from Sklearn.

I have used the below code:

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.90, min_df=2, max_features=1000, stop_words='english')
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(combi['tidy_tweet'])

The output is below:

(0, 302)  0.46871135687055143
  (0, 463)  0.5896490179849546
  (0, 738)  0.6577413621857342
  (1, 879)  0.3938403468675415
  (1, 131)  0.6145629375807904
  (1, 600)  0.6835218920644196
  (2, 79)   1.0
  (3, 557)  0.7040384885805177
  (3, 518)  0.44016705593507854
  (3, 888)  0.5572995329862621
  (4, 566)  1.0
  (5, 423)  0.586120951905663
  (5, 858)  0.4743403266916206
  (5, 69)   0.4637175931713698
  (5, 485)  0.4652198168550412
  (6, 121)  0.809676118019697
  (6, 894)  0.5868769751051355
  (7, 749)  0.47546741144240784
  (7, 992)  0.40382612331421974
  (7, 283)  0.6221668428341786
  (7, 883)  0.20713435439054187
  (7, 393)  0.22953868678391207
  (7, 432)  0.29836739781603

I can understand that the last column is TF-IDF value but what are the other columns .

Answer (score 0):

`tfidfvectorizer` is used to convert data to term-document matrix.
In the above output,the entries in first column,say `(0,302)`,`0` represents the index of the feature extracted and `302` is numerical notation of that particular feature.
For example, consider a simple dataframe as follows:

```
  col1
0  cat
1  dog
2  egg
3  god
4  cat
5  man
6  dog
```

To extract features from above data,

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',  min_df=0, encoding = 'utf-8')
X = vect.fit_transform(df['col1'].values.astype('U'))
```

The output given by the above code is as:

```
the document term matrix of data is
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (3, 3)    1.0
  (4, 0)    1.0
  (5, 4)    1.0
  (6, 1)    1.0
```

The first entry in first column of all the rows,(i.e 0,1,2....6) is nothing but the index of the extracted feature.The second entry,(i.e 0,1,2,3,0,4,1) represents the  numerical notation of the feature.You can observe this by using get_feature_names function of tfidfvectorizer.

```
print(vect.get_feature_names()[0])
print(vect.get_feature_names()[1])
print(vect.get_feature_names()[2])
print(vect.get_feature_names()[4])
print(vect.get_feature_names()[3])
```

The above code gives output as follows:

```
cat
dog
egg
man
god
```

It means that feature corresponding to the value 0 is cat,1 is dog,4 is man...and so on.